# WP LESSPHP -> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'load error:

Tags: php, wordpress, less, lessphp

I loaded lessphp in my wordpress theme - it's a full custom - but I do not understand why it can not correctly link the .less file.

to be clearer the current paths are these:

```
path:(themefolder/lessphp/lessc.inc.php)
path:(themefolder/lessphp/input.less) hemmm not working! yeaaa!
path:(themefolder/lessphp/output.css) hemmm not working! 

ps. for now, I am in wamp localhost.
```

Into head:

```
<?php
    //$inputPath = get_bloginfo("template_url")."/lessphp/input.less";

    require "lessphp/lessc.inc.php";
    $less = new lessc;
    $less->checkedCompile("lessphp/input.less", "lessphp/output.css");
?>
```

Before writing of course I read and did everything but, nothing, I still do not understand ...

The php error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'load error: failed to find lessphp/input.less' in C:\Server\www\shape\wp-content\themes\shape\lessphp\lessc.inc.php on line 1818

***How can I do??***

and, is it possible to change the classic path??

thank you.

Comment: Relative paths in PHP are nothing but trouble. Prefix your paths with `__DIR__` to make them relative to the current script directory. StackOverflow is full of questions like this

Comment: And while you're at it, make sure file permissions are set accordingly.

Comment: I read other post but not have a solution...
_DIR_ not working

and not working whit absolute path....

but thanks.

Comment: THE SOLUTION:

<?php

            $lesspath = dirname(__FILE__)."\yourpath\lessphp\lessc.inc.php";
            $inputFile = dirname(__FILE__).'\yourpath\input.less';
            $outputFile = dirname(__FILE__).'\yourpath\output.css';

            require_once $lesspath; $less = new lessc;

            // create a new cache object, and compile
            $less->compileFile($inputFile,$outputFile);

        ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/yourpath/output.css">

WORK.

Answer (score 0):

THE SOLUTION:

only wamp localhost:

Change the path from bloginfo("xxx") to php dirname(FILE).

```
<?php

    $lesspath = dirname(FILE)."\yourextrafolderpath\lessphp\lessc.inc.php";
    $inputFile = dirname(FILE).'\extrafolderpath\input.less';
    $outputFile = dirname(FILE).'\extrafolderpath\output.css';

    require_once $lesspath; $less = new lessc;

    // create a new cache object, and compile
    $less->compileFile($inputFile,$outputFile);

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/extrafolderpath/output.css">
```

Alternative way for wamp localhost & wordpress online:

```
<?php

        $lesspath = get_parent_theme_file_path()."\yourextrafolderpath\lessphp\lessc.inc.php";
        $inputFile = get_parent_theme_file_path().'\extrafolderpath\input.less';
        $outputFile = get_parent_theme_file_path().'\extrafolderpath\output.css';

        require_once $lesspath; $less = new lessc;

        // create a new cache object, and compile
        $less->compileFile($inputFile,$outputFile);

    ?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/extrafolderpath/output.css">
```

Tested... Work.